# How to fetch response from POST request AJAXutil in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, post, frontend, response

I am new to react. I made a post call and its working and getting response from that. Need to fetch the data. As the react version is old 0.13v its not supporting setState. Need to store in a variable and to fetch it. Below is the sample code.

````
    ajaxUtils.ajax({
      url: 'https://reqres.in/api/posts',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify({
    'Id': 'ABC',
    'state': 'BCD',
    'startDate': '2021-07-28',
     }),
      processData: false
    }).then(function(res) {
     this.setState({res: res});
     console.log('*** set result response', res);
     console.log('Our response', res);
     });
  }, ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think version 0.13 did support setState, as it is referenced in this changelog.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html

Can we see more of the class you are working in?